# Can't start cloned Laravel application that uses sail: Returns default 404 page with no errors in container logs

Tags: laravel, postgresql, laravel-sail

1. I cloned a new Laravel repository.
2. Then follow the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sail#installing-sail-into-existing-applications) to install Sail.
3. Copied the `.env` file as well.
4. Ran `sail up`, `sail npm install` `sail npm run dev`.
5. At this point, I received a `user root doesn't exist` error from the Postgres container. Also, the page at `localhost` was just the default 404 page recommending me to use Tinker etc. It wasn't the 404 page returned by the application.
6. Attached to the Postgres container, logged into the database using `sail` and password set before. Created superuser `root`.
7. Ran `sail down` and `sail up` to restart.
8. Migrated the database: `sail artisan migrate`
9. Still received the default 404 page. But this time I received no log errors.
10. After some time, I received some log errors saying `myapp-pgsql-1 | 2023-08-05 19:07:37.302 UTC [106] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet`.
11. Kept refreshing `localhost`, but there are no more error logs and I still see the default 404 page.

**Note:** When I run the app locally, it does run (even though I can't send any requests because Postgres is not installed locally).
Note: I use [colima](https://github.com/abiosoft/colima) for docker. I also tried with Docker Desktop but that didn't work either. Also, starting a fresh project with sail and colima works.

Edit: A screenshot:
[image: The 404 page I get when I go to localhost]

Comment: > `and I still see the default 404 page` <<<=== actually, this time show a screenshot of that 'default 404 page'? Did you turn on debug mode? This is on a production server, correct?-

Comment: This is just my personal pc. I am trying to clone and run a project my friend started. Doesn't the project run on debug mode by default? Thanks for asking for a screenshot, it will be useful. I will take a screenshot and post it when I can.

Comment: Herd is created just for MacOS. The debug mode is what's set in the .env.example file (and where you created a copy from). Back to basics new laravel and give that sail. Does it work? Awesome! Compare docker-compose.yml from working to non-working. If everything else fails, fall back to `laradock`. Check the `APP_URL` in your .env. does Herd / Sail know about it?

Comment: Thanks a lot for trying to help. Creating php project and adding sail works. My `.env` and `docker-compose` files should be ok because I use them on another system. I will check `laradock`. How can I check if Herd/Sail knows about `APP_URL`? I think the problem is about docker's connections since I am not getting my own applications 404 page.

Comment: What I would do Is compare working project with non-working project. You have something called 'winmerge' or 'meld' (linux). The non-working docker-compose.yml is very interesting. Also compare both .env files. APP_KEY should be different, rest *could* be equal. In Sail you can enter the container. Create a new file inside that container, in the `public` directory. I usually make it `phpinfo.php` with similar function inside. Then reach it from the outside. It can be as simple as editing the hosts file